# Can Perl's HTML::Selector::XPath be used for the general purpose of finding XPaths?

Tags: html, css, perl

Can Perl's HTML::Selector::XPath be used for the general purpose of finding XPaths?

```
  use HTML::Selector::XPath;

  my $selector = HTML::Selector::XPath->new("li#main");
  $selector->to_xpath; # //li[@id='main']

  # functional interface
  use HTML::Selector::XPath 'selector_to_xpath';
  my $xpath = selector_to_xpath('div.foo');
```

Comment: What language is this? What library? Please tag your questions with such details, in order for them to get the right kind of attention.

Comment: @Oded: It's Perl. Apart from that I fail to see an actual question

Comment: hi Oded hi Tomalak - thx for commenting. Yes it is perl  and i am working on a Perl-script that helps me to find Xpaths. I found out that i would probably can make use of HTML::Selector::XPath. That would be a great thing - if i can run this to get Xpaths...

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "finding xpaths".

Answer (score 3):

[HTML::Selector::XPath](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aSelector%3a%3aXPath) takes a CSS selector and converts it to an equivalent XPath expression.  It doesn't let you search an HTML file for matching elements.  Maybe you're looking for [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder%3a%3aXPath) or [HTML::Query](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aQuery).